# obtaining certain characters from a string by position

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSString *str = @"ABCDEFGHI";
```

I would like to get the characters into position.

For example, i would extract the first, third and fourth position character: "ACD"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up `-substringWithRange:`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *trimmedString=[str substringFromIndex:[str length]1];
NSString *trimmedString1=[str substringFromIndex:[str length]3];
NSString *trimmedString2=[str substringFromIndex:[str length]4];
```

and append them to get desired result.